# React - how to bind two attributes to one img tag

Tags: reactjs

I want to include the *src* & *width* attributes to the `<img>` tag. I used following code :

```
<img src={  p.productImgUrl }{ (p.bottleSize==='small' ? '"width=100px"' : '')} />
```

The error is as follows:

> Error: Unexpected token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the height and width using inline styles as follows

```
<img 
  src={  p.productImgUrl } 
  style={ p.bottleSize==='small' ? {width:'100px'} : {} } />
```

[React inline styles](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html)

or using the `width attribute`

```
<img 
  src={  p.productImgUrl } 
  width={ p.bottleSize==='small' ? '100px' : '' } />
```